# How can I make a div with an angled edge?

Tags: css

I have a simple div with a shadow and I was wondering how/if i can add an extra element to it. Here is the code:

```css
h3.widget-title{
    background-color:#aac955; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 37px #aed449;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 37px #aed449;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 37px #aed449;
    color:#444; padding:5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <h3 class="widget-title">Title</h3>
    <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

Here is what I am looking for: [image]

See the green edge. The idea is to get the h3 title and its style more to the front. Is such a thing possible through CSS?

Comment: :before and :after to the rescue

Comment: hey, thanks, but how do i add such a diagonal gradient to the shadow? Thanks

Comment: @RobbertT, you may cut the images in photoshop, combine them into one sprite and use them as `background-image` for the pseudo-elements suggested by @dachi. Or you can give us a real picture of what you really need, or an online example on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

I used the pseudo-elements `:before` and `:after` and used CSS code from this site: http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/ in order to make the hooks. Play a little and you will figure it out.